# How can i map over an object array with another array

Tags: arrays, date, dictionary

I have an array of dates that I am trying to use to map over an array of objects containing dates to find the corresponding date.

For example:

```
let dateArray = [
  {
    "day": "Today",
    "date": "December 28, 2021"
  },
  {
    "day": "Tomorrow",
    "date": "December 29, 2021"
  },
  {
    "day": "Thursday",
    "date": "December 30, 2021"
  },
  {
    "day": "Friday",
    "date": "December 31, 2021"
  }
]


let jsonData = [
          {
            "id": "300",
            "name": "item1",
            "showtimes": ["December 28, 2021", "December 30, 2021"]
          },
          {
            "id": "223",
            "name": "item2",
            "showtimes": ["January, 4 2022"]
          },
          {
            "id": "888",
            "name": "item3",
            "showtimes": ["December 28, 2021", "December 25, 2021", "December 29, 2021"]
          },
        ]
```

The idea here might be to use "dateArray" to map over "jsonData" so that I can get a modified array that contains objects with corresponding dates to today or tomorrow or Thursday etc. For example, for today I will like to get this new array:

```
[
      {
        "id": "300",
        "name": "item1",
        "showtimes": ["December 28, 2021", "December 30, 2021"]
      },
      {
        "id": "888",
        "name": "item3",
        "showtimes": ["December 28, 2021", "December 25, 2021", "December 29, 2021"]
      },
    ]
```

I was able to get here but this is far from what I want:

```
const result = dateArray.map(id => jsonData.find(o => o.showtimes.includes(id)))
```

Comment: You're comparing totally different string formats, why would you expect them to be included? You need to have a canonical representation to compare.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, the question has been edited

Comment: _"this is far from what I want"_ - what does it give you, and how does that compare to what you want? `id` is an _object_. Maybe you should try some basic debugging, use your IDE or e.g. https://pythontutor.com/javascript.html.